# Cloning hard drive question

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, clone

I run Win XP and Ubuntu on my desktop. The HDD that Windows is installed on appears to be getting ready to die (loud noises).

I'd like to clone it but don't know how it would affect my Linux.(installed on a secondary HDD) is there something I should do to keep the dual boot option?

To recap:

```
HDD 0: Windows xp
HDD 1: ubuntu
```

I'd like to clone HDD 0 and still have the grub menu.

I just wanted to restate my question so its far clearer.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you cloning it to? If they are on separate disks why do you think this would disrupt the linux drive?

Answer (score 1):

To clone the drive to another drive of the same kind, and with the same size or bigger, you can use **Clonezilla** (and clone the whole drive). This should not affect other drives.

See this link for more details about Clonezilla,

[clonezilla.org](http://clonezilla.org)

Clonezilla works if you can still read all sectors (at least all used sectors) of the drive.

---

*If there are bad sectors, it is better to use* **ddrescue** to clone the drive. It can save information from 'almost dead' sectors, and sectors near dead sectors. See this link for more details,

```
sudo apt-get install gddresue
```

Learn about it at the info page, which contains a lot of good information,

```
info ddrescue
```

and follow one of the examples.

---

Please be aware that Windows XP no longer receives any security updates.

Comment: Will ddrescue allow me to expand the filesystem after cloning? I'm going from 80 GB to 250.  I'll start looking at dd now.

Comment: Both `ddrescue` and Clonezilla will clone. They will not change anything, only copy each byte from the source drive to the target drive (except that Clonezilla will skip copying the content of unused blocks (that are not used for bootloader, partition table, files, and directories). - Both tools allow you to edit the partition table afterwards to expand the partition and filesystem and create new partitions depending on what you want. As usual, if you move the head end of the Ubuntu boot partition (root partition if /boot is a directory in that partition), you have to reinstall / repair grub.

Answer (score 0):

If you are cloning Windows to a separate disk, there shouldn't be a problem. If you want to have both OS on the same disk, you may have to update grub afterwards. I am running Ubuntu and Windows on the same disk without any problems.

Comment: I mainly was wondering if it would interrupt grub. But sudo update grub will fix it. I might also do upgrade to see if there are any new versions available.